# How to attach logcat error from mobile without using run inside android studio?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have a small project
the problem starts when the app works on the device without use run from inside Android Studio
so i want to extract the errors that appear in the application while it is running on the device without using Run or Debug 
I want to know what kind of mistakes are.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you need to getting logs in your device see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9807171/2383176) from @NitZRobotKoder

alternatively you can use some of log tracker/crash reporter tool, like: [Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics)

Comment: I deleted my answer added you +1, someone gave -1 to both of us